# Evaluate the surface integral of $\vec F=(-y+z,-z+x,-x+y)$ over the curve $\alpha (t,s)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Given $\vec F=(-y+z,-z+x,-x+y)$ I am asked to find the integral over the surface $\alpha$
$$\alpha(t,s)=(t\cos(s),t\sin(s),s)$$
 for $\quad 0\le s\le 2\pi$ and $\quad0\le t\le 1$

This after explaining the divergence theorem, but the surface is not closed and I have not found how to close it. How else can I integrate it?

Comment: I donot understand your question, could you refresh?

Comment: I am sure it is $s$  and it is supposed to be something similar to an helix

Comment: Then I would just use the parameterization and calculate it withoit using the divergence theorem. The integration will be relatively easy since you have linear functions as component of your vectorvalued function. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use that $\int \boldsymbol{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol{S}=\int \boldsymbol{F\cdot \hat{n}}dS$, where $\hat{n}$ is the unit vector pointing in the outward direction from the surface and given by the cross-product of two vectors that span up the surface.